# How to create new column with new names that has value from other column and keep values for the previous columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe_1 I would like to transform:

```
    Time        Not_paid Paid
0   morning     30       10  
1   afternoon   60       20
2   night       90       30
```

I would like to use the first column of dataframe_1 to create new columns with the others.
For example, 1 column 'Not_paid' + 'morning' that take the value 30, 1 column 'Not_paid' + 'afternoon' that take the value 60 and so on.

Expected output:

I would like to have the following df_2:

```
    Not_paid_morning Not_paid_afternon Not_paid_night Paid_morning Paid_afternoon Paid_night
0   30               60                90             10           20             30
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape with flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
out = df.set_index('Time').unstack().to_frame().T
out.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in out.columns]
```

Or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with transpose:

```
out = df.melt('Time', value_name=0)
out.index = out['variable'] + '_' + out['Time']

out = out[[0]].T
```

Or [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for flatten values with `product` for new columns names:

```
from  itertools import product
c = [f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in product(df.columns.difference(['Time'], sort=False),df['Time'])]

out = pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(df.drop('Time', axis=1).to_numpy(), 'f')], columns=c)
```

---

```
print (out)
   Not_paid_morning  Not_paid_afternoon  Not_paid_night  Paid_morning  \
0                30                  60              90            10   

   Paid_afternoon  Paid_night  
0              20          30
```